# How to map DBNull value with Dapper?

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm using Dapper and executing the following query, which is being mapped to a list of type `MyObject`. My problem with the default mapper is that I have a nullable `int` field in my table (`INOUT`) that holds integer values. One possible value is `NULL`, which is getting mapped into integer 0. How can I prevent this? I have to know if `INOUT` is NULL or 0.

```
public List<MyObject> GetSomething()
{
    using (IDbConnection db = GetOpenConnection())
    {
        return db.Query<MyObject>("Select * from tbl_foo").ToList<MyObject>();
    }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public int INOUT { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `int` type in is non-nullable, meaning that it can only hold integer values. To allow it to hold null *or* integer values, it will need to be type `Nullable<int>` or more simply `int?`.

To correct this, change `MyObject` to:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int? INOUT { get; set; }
}
```

This will allow the `INOUT` field to store either `null` or an integer value.